# std::shared_ptr<T[]> VS std::array<T, size>/std::vector<T>

Tags: c++, c++17, std, shared-ptr

So, I have a question, the answer to which I could not find. In C++ shared pointer has a constructor that can contain a raw array(std::shared_ptr<int[]>,for example.)

What are the benefits of using it compared to std::array or std::vector?

Tried to search, ask gpt. As for std::vector, there is a suggestion that memory allocation can be avoided with std::shared_ptr, but that doesn't explain why using this when there is a std::array

Comment: It boils down to the ownership model.  If you need an array with shared ownership, you need a shared_ptr.  If one object will own the array, you can use std::arry or std::vector.

Comment: Be careful with std::shared_ptr, usually std::unique_ptr is the better model. In the end they will all allocate. std::array<> on stack, std::vector<T>/std::make_unique<T[]>/std::make_shared<T[]> allocate on the heap. And std::vector<T> can also reallocate to when items are added at runtime. If you need to allocate only once you could uste std::make_unique<std::array<T,N>>

Comment: And I would not quite trust the answers of chatGPT yet. What is the actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Most of the time you should avoid arrays in favour of `std::array` or `std::vector`, but every now and then you still need a raw array.  The Standard Library is just filling in blanks so that the case is covered.

Comment: One benefit is that with `std::shared_ptr<int[]>` or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` you could create uninitialized array. `std::vector<int>` will always initialize values. See `std::make_shared_for_overwrite()` and `std::make_unique_for_overwrite()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of containers and smart pointers depends on usage and design:

```
std::vector creates a dynamic array of objects on heap
std::array creates a static array of object on stack, size known at compile time
std::shared_ptr<int[]> keeps the reference count of the resource, here resource is a pointer to an array
```

std::array is on the stack, if usage is limited to a scope and size is known at compile time then array is fine.

when you want to share the ownership of the resource across functions, containers, thread(multi-thread safe object or const), shared_ptr is suitable. But using shared_ptr doesnt mean we can avoid allocation, you need to pass a resource pointer which it manages.

As for vector, it allocates data on heap but need to take care that vector itself should not go out of scope otherwise destructor will free up the resource as it doesnt have refrence count like shared_pointer.

If you use vector ,atleast one allocation is done.

If you use array, its on stack so no allocation is done.

shared_ptr takes a pointer, which has to be allocated somewhere. other allocation is of control block. thus 2 allocation until std::make_shared is used which can optimize the number of allocations.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike all other listed options, `std::array` requires the size to be known at compile-time, and doesn't store the elements on the heap (unless it itself is on the heap).

`std::vector<T>` can work with a size not known at compile-time, and should be your default choice in that case. It always stores the elements on the heap.

`std::unique_ptr<T[]>` can be thought of as a stripped down `std::vector`. It doesn't know its size, which saves a tiny bit of memory (`sizeof(std::unique_ptr<T[]>)` is normally `sizeof(void *)`, while `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is normally `3 * sizeof(void *)`).

Because it doesn't store its size, there's very few things it can do out of the box: it can't be copied (only moved), it can't insert or remove elements, etc. You can do all of this manually if you store the size separately, but then it's just `std::vector` with extra steps.

`std::shared_ptr<T[]>` adds an extra feature to `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` - shared ownership, like any other `std::shared_ptr<??>`.